# Open Excel with ANSI encoding, in excel 2010

Tags: excel, encoding, utf-8, ansi

I have excel file with ANSI encoding(it was generated in Excel 97), but now i need open this file with Excel 2010, but seems it have problem with opening ANSI encoding, because instead of russian characters i see bad characters :( 
How can i open this file in Excel 2010 ? I tried convert xls file from ANSI to UTF-8 via notepad++ but it can't convert this file :(

Answer (score 1):

This is because the default language on your PC is set to English not Russian

Therefore you will only be able to read Russian if it were encoded as UTF-8, UTF-16 (Unicode) or UTF-32

To convert the ASCII-8bit-Russian text you have to a unicode derivative:

1- Copy the Russian text
2- In Notepad++, open new file, change Encoding -> Character Sets -> Eastern European

3- Paste

4- Then to convert to Unicode, go again same menu: Encoding -> "Encode in UTF-8" and hopefully it will become readable

Another option is that the file you copied was UTF-8 but without the byte order mark (a hidden character at the beginning of a file telling programs the file is UTF-8)... If that's the case some programs detect the encoding as ASCII instead of UTF-8. To solve repeat same steps as above but in step 2 instead of choosing Easter European, choose ANSI

The above steps apply for most languages. You just need to guess the original encoding before pasting in notepad++, then convert through the same menu to an alternate Unicode-based encoding to see if things become readable.

Most languages exist in 2 forms of encoding:
1- The old legacy form, only 8 bits, was used initially by most computers. 8 bits only allowed 256 possibilities, 128 of them where the regular latin and control characters, the final 128 bits were read differently depending on the PC language settings
2- The new Unicode standard (up to 32 bit) give a unique code for each character in all currently known languages and plenty more to come. if a file is unicode it should be understood on any PC with the language's font installed. Note that even UTF-8 goes up to 32 bit and is just as broad as UTF-16 and UTF-32 only it tries to stay 8 bits with latin characters just to save up disk space